# Using Hibernate to Query Range from 2 Different property

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

im new to hibernate queries. i have a question regarding the hibernate range search. what i want is to search a range from 2 different column 
below is my illustrations

in the DB:

```
 Start_No | End_No
  3000    | 4000
```

my hibernate queries is like this

```
session = getSession();
            session.buildLockRequest(new LockOptions(LockMode.NONE));
            Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(CardRange.class);

if(!IMXUtil.isEmpty(s_startNo) && !IMXUtil.isEmpty(s_endNo)){
                crit.add(Restrictions.ge("startNo", Long.parseLong(s_endNo)));

                crit.add(Restrictions.ge("startNo", Long.parseLong(s_startNo)));

            }

ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
            projList.add(Projections.property("cardRangeId"));
            projList.add(Projections.property("startNo"));
            projList.add(Projections.property("endNo"));
            projList.add(Projections.property("issuerId"));
            projList.add(Projections.property("status"));
            projList.add(Projections.property("createdDate"));
            projList.add(Projections.property("lastModifiedDate"));
            crit.setProjection(projList);
            crit.setFirstResult(iDisplayStart);
            crit.setMaxResults(iDisplayLength);

return crit.list();
```

the output is like this

if i put 3500 to 3600 = it still falls in range with 3000 to 4000 in the db 
and display the output. how i be able to create a hibernate criteria to satisfy this search?

Comment: If you are looking for a range of values between start_no and end_no then you can use a simple where condition. 

where start_no <=:param1 AND end_no >= :parma2

Comment: Now you are doing something like `where start_no > :endNoParam and start_no > :startNoParam`, which is obviously not what you described.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for creating criteria are

1.create Session
2. add projections 
3.then add restrictions.
your projection list seems fine.

Do the following to your criterion (calling methods on Restrictions class returns criterion object),

Define criterion object for each condition

Criterion c1 = Restrictions.ge("startNo",Long.parseLong(s_startNo));
Criterion c2 = Restrictions.le("endNo",Long.parseLong(s_endNo));

add these to criteria object

Criterion c3 = Restrictions.and(c1,c3);
crit.add(c3);

In a single line

crit.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.ge("startNo",Long.parseLong(s_startNo)),Restrictions.le("endNo",Long.parseLong(s_endNo))));